# how to add columns to describe() table

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a dataframe, used describe() on the dataframe, then inverted the describe() table.

Now, I want to add a column to this new table of skewness and kurtosis values.

I want to add a "Skewness" column and "Kurtosis" column to the right of "max" column. The Skewness column will have all of the skewness values of each row. The Kurtosis column will have the Kurtosis values of each row.

**What you see so far is the transposed describe() table I called "summary_transpose"**

```
                 count   mean    std   min    25%    50%    75%    max
Unnamed: 0      1000.0  499.5  288.8   0.0  249.8  499.5  749.2  999.0
FINAL_MARGIN    1000.0   -1.2   15.3 -39.0   -8.0   -2.0    8.0   28.0
SHOT_NUMBER     1000.0    6.4    4.7   1.0    3.0    5.0    9.0   23.0
PERIOD          1000.0    2.5    1.1   1.0    2.0    2.0    4.0    6.0
SHOT_CLOCK       979.0   11.8    5.4   0.3    8.0   11.5   15.0   24.0
DRIBBLES        1000.0    1.6    2.9   0.0    0.0    1.0    2.0   23.0
TOUCH_TIME      1000.0    2.9    2.6  -4.3    0.9    2.1    4.2   20.4
SHOT_DIST       1000.0   12.3    7.8   0.1    5.6   10.4   18.5   41.6
PTS_TYPE        1000.0    2.2    0.4   2.0    2.0    2.0    2.0    3.0
CLOSE_DEF_DIST  1000.0    3.6    2.3   0.0    2.1    3.1    4.7   19.8
FGM             1000.0    0.5    0.5   0.0    0.0    0.0    1.0    1.0
PTS             1000.0    1.0    1.1   0.0    0.0    0.0    2.0    3.0
```

Comment: Please post the dataframe as text not image

Answer (score 0):

The code below adds the Skewness and Kurtosis columns next to the *max* column.

```
import scipy.stats as stats
summary = round(df.describe(), 1) # rounds each value to 0.1
summary_transpose = summary.T # transposes the original summary table

summary_transpose['Skewness'] = stats.skew(df._get_numeric_data(), nan_policy='omit')
summary_transpose['Kurtosis'] = stats.kurtosis(df._get_numeric_data(), nan_policy='omit')
```

Comment: I get an error — unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Can you share the snippet of code causing the error?

Comment: I edited your answer. Sorry to make a mess of things. You can go back in and edit it so that it will run properly

Comment: I'm guessing you got that error because your original dataframe has non-numeric columns. I have edited the code above to only retrieve numeric data when calculating skewness and kurtosis

Comment: Yes, it does have non-numeric columns. Code seems to be working, however, the SHOT_CLOCK row doesn't compute a skewness.

Comment: What Is the value shown for the skewness of the SHOT_CLOCK column?

Comment: "NaN". This is what displays for both skewness and kurtosis.

Comment: I see. That means the SHOT_CLOCK column has NaN values which causes skew and kurtosis to return NaN. You can instruct the functions to perform the calculations ignoring NaN values by adding the nan_policy='omit' parameter. I have edited the answer. Let me know if it fixes the issue.